# Adding overlay to video which fades in and out intermittently

Tags: ffmpeg

first time posting. That said I've come up against a challenge and I need some input.

I've been trying to create a command to add a "watermark" or overlay to a vide which fades in, stays on screen for a certain duration and then fades out. This type of effect is common in "screeners" where a disclaimer like "for your consideration" fades in and out periodically.

I am currently able to do this by creating a separate overlay file which is of the desired duration, with a fade in and fade out. I then loop this overlay and achieve the desired effect. However, for a couple of reasons, I'd like to be able to achieve this in a single command.

this is what I need the command to do- any input would be greatly appreciated!

the overlay must fade in and fade out, with a total duration of 30 seconds

the overlay must reappear (with fade in and fade out, as above) every 5 minutes, for the entire duration of the main clip.

the overlay may consist of the any of the following:

a .png

custom text (currently using drawtext to generate the text)

a .mov file (an overlay with an animated intro, the last frame of which is looped to give desired duration)

in the case of the animated overlay, ideally the video overlay will not fade in but will fade out, so, for each instance where the overlay appears, the .mov is playing from the beginning, looping the last frame, and fading out.

.png + custom text (both fade in and out)

.mov + custom text (custom text fades in, both fade out)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

loop:

```
ffmpeg -i "input 1.mp4" -loop 1 -i logo.png -filter_complex "
[1:v]
fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,
fade=t=out:st=29:d=1:alpha=1,
loop=loop=-1:size=7500[fg];
[0:v][fg]overlay=W/2-w/2:H/2-h/2:shortest=1
" -c:a copy output.mp4 -y
```

size=7500 is number of frames 25 fps * 300 sec